dmc card responsivity - plotly dash
I've got multiple dmc.card items within a dash app layout. I've got them set to a specific height and width. I've also instilled base, sm, md, lg values to account for a responsive change in screen settings.
I'm trying to achieve the same response that the traditional dbc.Card performs. That is, when the screen size is reduced, the cards keep their same layout but reduce in width.
I don't want the cards to split into separate rows.
Is there a way for dmc.card to operate the same way?
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_mantine_components as dmc

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

carddbc = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.P('', className = 'card-text'),
            ]
        ),
    ], 
    style = {'height':'100%'}
)

card1 = dmc.Card(
    html.Div(children = [
        dcc.Checklist(['','','','',''], 
                     ),
    ],
    ),
    w={"base": 100, "sm": 180,"md": 300, "lg": 300},
    py={"base": "xs", "sm": "md", "lg": "xl"},
    bg={"base": "blue.7", "sm": "red.7", "lg": "green.7"},
    withBorder=True,
    shadow='sm',
    radius='md',
    h=275,
)

card2 = dmc.Card(
    html.Div(children = [
        dcc.Checklist(['','','','',''], 
                     ),
    ],
    ),
    w={"base": 100, "sm": 180,"md": 300, "lg": 300},
    py={"base": "xs", "sm": "md", "lg": "xl"},
    bg={"base": "blue.7", "sm": "red.7", "lg": "green.7"},
    withBorder=True,
    shadow='sm',
    radius='md',
    h=275,
)

card3 = dmc.Card(
    html.Div(children = [
        dcc.Checklist(['','','','',''], 
                     ),
    ],
    ),
    w={"base": 100, "sm": 180,"md": 300, "lg": 300},
    py={"base": "xs", "sm": "md", "lg": "xl"},
    bg={"base": "blue.7", "sm": "red.7", "lg": "green.7"},
    withBorder=True,
    shadow='sm',
    radius='md',
    h=275,
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
        ], xs = 2, sm = 2, md = 2, lg = 2
        ),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(carddbc, width = {'size':3}),
                dbc.Col(carddbc, width = {'size':3}),
                dbc.Col(carddbc, width = {'size':3}),
            ], justify = 'center'),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                ], xs = 4, sm = 4, md = 4, lg = 4),
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                dcc.Graph()
                            ], 
                            ),
                            dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col(html.Div(card1), className = ''),    
                            dbc.Col(html.Div(card2), className = ''),
                            dbc.Col(html.Div(card3), className = ''),
                            ]
                            )
                        ]),
                    ], 
                    )
                    ])
                ], xs = 8, sm = 8, md = 8, lg = 8),
            ])
        ], xs = 10, sm = 10, md = 10, lg = 10)
    ])
], fluid = True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)


Instead of using grid component you could go for flexbox so that all the cards lie in the same row
This will work
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_mantine_components as dmc

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


card_template = lambda: dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            # Optional title in the card
            html.H5("Card Title", className="card-title"),
            # Checklist inside the card
            dcc.Checklist(
                options=[
                    {"label": "Option 1", "value": "1"},
                    {"label": "Option 2", "value": "2"},
                    {"label": "Option 3", "value": "3"},
                    {"label": "Option 4", "value": "4"},
                    {"label": "Option 5", "value": "5"},
                ],
                value=[],  # Initial selected values
            ),
        ]
    ),
    style={
        "width": "100%",  # Adjust the width based on the column size
        "height": 275,  # Fixed height
        "background-color": "#d5f5e3",  # Light green background
        "border": "1px solid #ccc",  # Border styling
        "border-radius": "10px",  # Rounded corners
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",  # Light shadow
    },
    outline=True,  # Optionally have an outline border
)

card1 = card_template()
card2 = card_template()
card3 = card_template()

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col([], xs=2, sm=2, md=2, lg=2),  
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Row(
                        [
                            dbc.Col(card1, style={"flex": "1"}), 
                            dbc.Col(card2, style={"flex": "1"}),
                            dbc.Col(card3, style={"flex": "1"}),
                        ],
                        style={"display": "flex", "flex-wrap": "nowrap", "justify-content": "center"},  
                    ),
                    xs=10, sm=10, md=10, lg=10,  
                ),
            ],
            justify="center", 
        ),
    ],
    fluid=True, 
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


Nice. No wrap works. Is there a way the reduce the width (like the dbc cards) with the reduction in the screen size. The dbc cards are smooth, whereas the dmc cards are very sudden

@jonboy added dbc cards
